# Java Window Builder Error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

Just heard of Window Builder so I was working on a piece of code, and the application just takes your name and returns it in a label.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class app {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private static String text;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    app window = new app();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public app() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel(text);
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                text = textField.getText();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Check My Name");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                lblNewLabel.setText("Your name is " + text + "!");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

}
```

Don't understand why it works sometimes and not all the time. I am new to window builder so I would appreciate detailed answers.

Why is it not working? Can you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

> Don't understand why it works sometimes and not all the time.

In the future, be explicit. What works sometimes and what doesn't work? Tell us the steps you do to produce the error.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    lblNewLabel.setText("Your name is " + text + "!");
```

I'm guessing the problem is with the above code. A mouseClicked event is generate when a mousePressed and mouseReleased event is generated at the same mouse point. If you move the mouse even 1 pixel between the two events the mouseClicked event will not be generated.

Don't use a MouseListener.

Instead a button was designed to be used with an `ActionListener`. Implement the `actionPerformed(...)` method and add an `ActionListener` to your button. The code in the listener will be the same.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more information.

If this doesn't solve your problem then your question needs to be updated with more information on how to create the problem.